# Vim NERDTree increases the command line size and doesn't shrink it back

Tags: vim, vimrc, macvim, nerdtree

I am using MacVim 9.0 with NERDTree. Some commands in the NERDTree cause the command line to increase in height to display the full command description. (For example, pressing `m` in the NERDTree window, to "modify" a file.)

**The issue is**: after the command is complete (confirmed or canceled), command line is cleared but does not shrink back (which I am used to with other Vim installations I have). Curiously, executing `:set cmdheight` yields value of `1`, but I can clearly see that visually the command line occupies several lines.

Do you know what setting can be causing this? Or, otherwise, what is missing to "autoshrink" the command line back to its default value  after it is cleared?

Comment: What version of Vim? I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I am using Vim 9.0. I have updated the question with the same information. Yes, I cannot reproduce it in other environments I have either. Yet, I cannot figure out what setting in this environment causes this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an incompatibility between nerdtree and vim 9 and is [tracked here](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/issues/1321).

The current workarounds are:

- `let g:NERDTreeMinimalMenu=1` in `~/.vimrc`
- Using [this fork](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/pull/1322/files)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about the "MinimalMenu" option, I actually prefer it since I never read the full text anymore.